# When robot rotates, pose arrows diverges(which makes turning difficult)

Tags: gazebo, navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
There is no problem in navigation except this one. Robot tries to choose the closest path possible but this makes robot rotate sharp turn. That is why in the middle of narrow path, robot stops since pose arrays diverges (like at the beginning) I saw from internet that other robots may not choose the closest path and make a smooth turn but I don't know how to do it ( as I know, it can be done by neutral_cost) Yet, I did not know how to add cost parameter. So it seems there are 2 choices:

1- find a way to make sharp turns without any divergence of pose arrays

2-find a way to write cost parameter and make sharp turns smooth.

I'm really counting on you guys thanks for helping.

Note: this is the video I made for this problem.    https://youtu.be/PApn4dh8nnM

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364106/when-robot-rotates,-pose-arrows-diverges(which-makes-turning-difficult)/) by [asdfg123](https://answers.ros.org/users/60880/asdfg123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-10-25**:
The video is "private"

**Comment by [asdfg123](https://answers.ros.org/users/60880/asdfg123/) on 2020-10-25**:
My apologies, I changed it. Please try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer 1)

Assuming you are using [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) you should lower the values of `odom_alpha1` and `odom_alpha4`. This will reduce the amount of noise added during the "predict" step during sharp rotations.

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asdfg123](https://answers.ros.org/users/60880/asdfg123/) on 2020-10-26**:
it works when I made odom_alpha1 and4 0. Unfortunately, still robot stops in the middle of path(I upload a new video for it.). Can you have any solution for that? Thanks for answering.

The address of the video: https://youtu.be/IRZb3BbVVAk

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-10-27**:
I would consider increasing the global costmap's (read: the one that the global planner works on) inflation radius. This will keep it further away from walls. Glad I could help!

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-10-27**:
And I would not reduce the odom_alpha terms to 0. That is saying "I have 100% perfect odometry when I turn" and we can all agree that is not the case. Try smaller values, but not zero. Cheers

**Comment by [asdfg123](https://answers.ros.org/users/60880/asdfg123/) on 2020-10-28**:
thank you.